# Limit of iteration convergence

Tags: fixed-point-iteration

The iteration as given to me is this:

$x_{n+1}=F(x_n)=sin(x_n), x_0=1$

so I think that the start of the iteration would look something like this:

$x_0=1$

$x_1=sin(1)=.841$

$x_2=sin(sin(1))=sin(.841)=.7456$ and so on.

My professor said this iteration converges, but how do we know that? The only test for convergence I could find in my notes is that the iteration will converge if $|g'(a)|<1$. In this problem, is $g(x_n)=sin(x_n)$ since $g(x_n)=x_{n+1}$? Or is $g(x)=1-sin(x)/cos(x)$?

Also, what is the limit of this iteration, and how fast is the convergence?

Answer (score 2):

In this special case you can avoid the criterion of the derivative. Observe that any $x_n$ is of course non negative and that (since $\sin(x)\leq x$ for $x\geq 0$)
$$
x_{n+1}\leq x_n.
$$
Therefore $\{x_n\}$ is a non negative, monotone non-increasing sequence. *As such* it has a limit
$$
\exists \ell\geq 0:\quad x_n\to \ell.
$$
Now you can prove that $\ell=0$. In fact, if $\ell>0$, then  $\sin(\ell)\not=\ell$, whereas  a necesessary condition for $\ell$ being the limit of $x_n$ is $ \sin(\ell)=\ell$.